# Azure Portal : Azure Cosmos Db Account : Networking : "There is already an operation in progress that requires exclusive lock"

Tags: azureportal

Scenario :

- Go to azure Portal
- Somehow, have a "Azure Cosmos Db Account" resource
- Open it and go to its "Networking" tab.
- In the right-side panel, go to the "Public access" tab
- Toggle "selected networks"
- A new pair of text boxes appears below to let you enter an IP
- Enter an IP
- click "Save"

**EXPECTED :** The new IP gets saved and added to the list of allowed IPs.

**OBSERVED (BAD) :** An error message appears in the top-right corner of the Azure Portal UI :

> "There is already an operation in progress that requires exclusive
> lock"

What lock could this possibly refer to ?
The problem is that this is a very generic error message. So I guess my question is : What can "lock" the creation of a new IP in the context of Networking settings on a CosmosDb account?

Answer (score 0):

I retried several times : I didn't work.

**I retried 10 minutes later (having left the tab open the whole time, and just clicked on "Save") : It finally worked!**

It could be that this "lock" is just Azure Portal being very slow to query something required on this page. Or that there's an overused resource in the background (your company's subscription is too cheap?). I suspect the first explanation because even when it worked, the frontend kept telling me that the changes had not been saved when I tried to leave the page. And yet, they were.

I don't know the root cause but I thought I'd sahre that the problem "fixed itself".